# Create an infopath form using existing SharePoint 2013 list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I have a new SharePoint 2013 list from which I created an InfoPath 2013 form and added all the field, and then associated some rules to those fields (hidden when condition x =y type , etc.). However when I then published the form, I cannot enter any data in the form, its as if all that exists are the headings, with no data entry fields available - please help?

Answer (score 0):

“x” and “y” in your condition example `(hidden when condition x = y type , etc.)` are fields. Is it right?

If you have not set the **default value** for a field, the field value is **empty** (**blank**). So, `x = empty` and `y = empty`. The condition is met because `x = y (empty = empty)`, then the relative field will be hidden.

Set the **default values** for the fields to make these fields have different values.

Comment: As the fields (There are around 80 of them) which I want to hide are all drop down boxes - could I add a default value of "Select Option" which will then allow the field to show and then be hidden when the intial field which is also a drop down box has its option (From around 70 options) selected?